# Custom Django Form + Inline Error Messages

Tags: django, forms

I'd like to know how can use Django's automatic form generation...

```
<form action="/contact/" method="POST">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

To achieve the following output (note the custom field in the middle of the form and error class within the wrapping div).

```
<form action="/contact/" method="POST">

    <div class="input error">
        <label for="id_subject">E-mail subject:</label>
        <span>Error Message</span>
    </div>

    <div class="input error">
        <label for="id_message">Your message:</label>
        <span>Error Message</span>
    </div>

    <!-- CUSTOM CONTAINER -->
    <div class="custom-container">
        <h2>Custom Content</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="input error">
        <label for="id_sender">Your email address:</label>
        <span>Error Message</span>
    </div>

    <div class="input error">
        <label for="id_cc_myself">CC yourself?</label>
        <span>Error Message</span>
    </div>

    <div><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Form.as_*` methods are pretty much just scaffolding. As soon as you want to do anything past just listing the fields in a consistent manor, you shouldn't be using them any more.

Using some of the logic in the documentation about [reusable form templates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#reusable-form-templates) you should be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: I looked at the reusable form templates - but in this case it's not about reusability but more about customization.

I am fine with hard coded form as long as I can get the error classes working.

Comment: You're example code shows that you want a custom container in the middle, so again, you can't rely on the `as_*` methods, as you *do* want customization. To clarify, there is currently no way to output HTML a single field using the logic contained within these "scaffolding" methods.

Answer (score 4):

You can checkout django-uni-form, http://github.com/pydanny/django-uni-form it will get you a little closer to what you are trying to do with the wrapping divs.

I agree with SmileyChris that you will be hard pressed to find a generic convenience method that allows you do so much.

But, between django-uni-form and judicious use of [widgets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) you can get close.

Comment: django-uni-form has a layout module which handles this exactly problem just nicely.